# Cant list conversations for current_user that is recipient of the conversation

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, list, foreign-keys

I have a problem listing one of my models.. I am following the tutorial http://josephndungu.com/tutorials/gmail-like-chat-application-in-ruby-on-rails
In this tutorial you make a conversation that has a `recipient_id` and a `sender_id` these are both foreign keys to the conversation table. the current_user is set on either recipient or sender when the conversation is made.

-I can only list the current_user.conversations when the current_user is a sender.
-When i try with a current_user that is a recipient I get no result.

-Figured out that in my user model I have a has_many conversations with a foreign_key `:sender_id`.  When I change this to `recipient_id`, then only the current_user that is a recipient can list conversations.

-With this I assume that I need to have two foreign keys referencing the same user? What can I do to get conversations to list for both current_users?

User.rb "model"

```rails
has_many :conversations, class_name: "Conversation", :foreign_key => :sender_id
```

listing conversation for current_user:

```html
<% current_user.conversations.each do |conversation| %>

    <p>hi</p>
    <% end %>
```

Conversation.rb "model"

```rails
class Conversation < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :sender, :foreign_key => :sender_id, class_name: 'User'
  belongs_to :recipient, :foreign_key => :recipient_id, class_name: 'User'

  has_many :messages, dependent: :destroy

  validates_uniqueness_of :sender_id, :scope => :recipient_id

  scope :involving, -> (user) do
    where("conversations.sender_id =? OR conversations.recipient_id =?",user.id,user.id)
  end

  scope :between, -> (sender_id,recipient_id) do
    where("(conversations.sender_id = ? AND conversations.recipient_id =?) OR (conversations.sender_id = ? AND conversations.recipient_id =?)", sender_id,recipient_id, recipient_id, sender_id)
end

end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that in your `User.rb` model you are saying that *The conversations of this user are those whose sender_id is this user*. That is the reason why when you use `current_user.conversations` you only get those records where `sender_id` is the current user.

I would do the following in your `User.rb` model:

```
has_many :conversations_started, class_name: "Conversation", :foreign_key => :sender_id
has_many :conversations_continued, class_name: "Conversation", :foreign_key => :recipient_id
```

This way you would be able to invoke:

```
current_user.conversations_started
```

or

```
current_user.conversations_continued
```

However, if you want to be able to list them all, you will need to define an additional method in your `User.rb` model:

```
def conversations
  conversations_started + conversations_continued
end
```

If a user can start a conversation with itself, I would add `.uniq` at the end of the `conversations` method

Comment: I was stuck on this all last night! thank you so much!! works like a charm!

Comment: How about  `conversations_started | conversations_continued` instead of `+` and then uniq?